# Um método setter pode receber como parâmetro um getter + valor?

Tags: java, método, parâmetros, getters-setters

Criei os métodos assessores *setter* e *getter* para o atributo saldo.

***É correto usar esses assessores um dentro do outro?*** Um sendo usado como parâmetro para o outro.

Mais especificamente o `getSaldo()` sendo parâmetro do `setSaldo()` que está dentro do método `sacar()`.

A linha:

```
this.setSaldo(this.getSaldo() - saque);
```

O código de exemplo em Java:

```
public class ContaBanco {
    private int saldo;

    public int getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }

   public void setSaldo(int saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo;
   }

   public void sacar(int saque){
            //this.saldo = this.saldo - saque;
            this.setSaldo(this.getSaldo() - saque);
   }

}
```

O código em si **funcionou**. Mas eu não sei se é **correto** e dentro dos padrões dessa forma.

O objeto de teste:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ContaBanco c1 = new ContaBanco();
        c1.setSaldo(500);
        c1.sacar(100);
    }
```

Comment: **Muito grato pelos esclarecimentos @Piovezan e @maniero** Pelo que entendi, nesse caso do exemplo o uso dos assessores seria **opcional** para facilitar a escrita e compreensão do código, sendo mais necessário somente em casos de código com mais "recursos/complexo" para melhor aproveitamento dos setters e getters, sem escrever código desnecessariamente

Comment: Agora você pode votar em todas perguntas e respostas do site que achar interessante.

Comment: @rafax23 Se você estiver se referindo aos acessores privados (autoencapsulamento) que o Fowler falou, sim (aliás seria esse mesmo o termo? Acessor? Assessor? Fiquei na dúvida agora, acho que não existe assessar em PT, só assessorar, eu chamo os getters + setters conjuntamente de manipuladores). Se fala de acessores públicos ou protegidos, aí eu prefiro dizer que eles só devem existir quando fazem sentido para a interface de utilização que você está querendo oferecer aos clientes dos objetos daquela classe, sem necessariamente haver uma relação de 1 para 1 entre os mesmos e os campos internos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não há problema em fazer isso. Porém aí tem uma questão que a utilização desse tipo de padrão cria: o código fica um pouco menos [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) e tem duas formas de acessar o campo, de forma direta e indireta. Não é o fim do mundo, mas passa ter que pensar sobre o uso.

Conceitualmente falando o mais correto seria só chamar através do método acessador, assim fica mais DRY e garante que o aceso é feito de maneira uniforme em todos os pontos. Mas há motivos de performance ou até de semântica diferente que se deseja naquele momento.

É claro que se é sabido que o método não faz nada extra e é uma indireção em cima do acesso ao campo de forma pura, então eu questiono um pouco a criação desse tipo de método. Eu até entendo que isso é necessário por uma deficiência da linguagem.

Tem que entender que se mudar a forma de acessar o campo se pegar o seu valor pelo método essa mudança se refletirá no que pegou, e se usar o campo essa mudança não será percebida no acesso direto. Tenha isso em mente na decisão.

Use o que for mais adequado para intenção, e na dúvida parece que o método é o melhor, já que ele foi criado.

Escreva o código que faça sentido, não o que atende padrões. Quando o padrão fizer sentido, ok, mas fazer sentido vem antes do padrão.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

Queria complementar a resposta do Maniero com uma coisa que acho que faltou falar.

> Criei os métodos assessores setter e getter para o atributo saldo.

Precisava mesmo ter criado? É importante diferenciar entre a interface exposta pelo objeto e os detalhes de implementação que existem dentro dele. Sua conta tem um campo interno chamado `saldo`, mas ele poderia não existir, poderia haver uma lista  histórica de operações financeiras que você percorre somando os resultados para obter o saldo atual no momento em que chama o `getSaldo()` (por exemplo).

Com essa diferenciação você protege a interface externa do seu objeto, que tende a ser mais estável, sem perder oportunidade de conseguir alterar os detalhes internos conforme necessário.

Faz sentido esse setter? Quer dizer, faz sentido disponibilizar uma operação de alterar o saldo de uma conta bancária para um valor arbitrário? Ou o que você realmente precisa na sua conta são operações (métodos públicos) de crédito e débito? Que alteram o saldo de maneira controlada. Pense nisso.

Sobre haver um `setSaldo()` interno, **privado**, o Martin Fowler [fala a respeito](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/SelfEncapsulation.html) mas não o impõe. Mas isso é bem diferente de disponibilizá-lo para uso público por todos os clientes do objeto, sendo que o objeto pode não ter a necessidade de expor essa alteração arbitrária de saldo.